# Why do statistics get out of date so quickly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, statistics

We have a somewhat complex SQL update query which gets run a few times a month.  Most of the time it seems to run really fast, but on some databases, it takes a really long time.  After running an "UPDATE STATISTICS" on the tables involved, the update immediately runs quickly again.  We finally set up a nightly task which calls UPDATE STATISTICS on all the tables in the database.  But that didn't seem to fix the problem.  We're still ending up having to run "UPDATE STATISTICS" manually each time.  Why would statistics go stale so quickly?

Here's approximately what the query looks like:

```
UPDATE DataTableA
SET DataTableA.IndexedColumn1 = 123456789, DataTableA.Flag1 = 1
FROM DataTableA WITH (INDEX(IX_DataTableA))
INNER JOIN GroupingTableA ON GroupingTableA.ForeignKey1 = GroupingTableA.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN LookupTableA ON DataTableA.ForeignKey3 = LookupTableA.PrimaryKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupingTableB ON DataTableA.IndexedColumn2 = GroupingTableB.IndexedColumn2
WHERE GroupingTableB.IndexedColumn1 = 123456789
AND DataTableA.IndexedColumn1 IS NULL
AND DataTableA.IndexedColumn2 IN ( ... 300 entries here ... )
AND DataTableA.Deleted = 0
AND GroupingTableA.Date <= GroupingTableB.EndDate
AND GroupingTableA.Date >= DATEADD(month, -1, GroupingTableB.StartDate)
AND LookupTableA.Column2 = 1
AND DataTableA.Status1 IN (1, 3)
AND DataTableA.Status2 NOT IN (1, 3, 9)
```

DataTableA contains millions of rows.
GroupingTableA and GroupingTableB each contain tens of thousands of rows.
LookupTableA contains dozens of rows.
Index IX_DataTableA is an index on (IndexedColumn1 ASC, IndexedColumn2 ASC)

Comment: Through trial and error, we determined that the GroupingTableB in the above example is what's getting out of date.  The problem still occurs, but we worked around it by calling "UPDATE STATISTICS" on that table each time we do an insert into it.  Not exactly the ideal solution...

Comment: I know this question is old, but for what it's worth, the moment you put a condition on `GroupingTableB` in the WHERE clause, it logically converts its `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You have 3 conditions like this. If you want the `LEFT JOIN` to actually function as a proper `OUTER` join, then those conditions must be moved to the `ON` clause in the `LEFT JOIN`. I'm just sayin'... :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your statistics will matter as much if you are forcing it to use a specific index (`WITH (INDEX(IX_DataTableA))`

Are you sure you know better than the optimizer?

I would start by looking at the execution plan for a fast update and a slow update.  Also, are the number of records being updated comparable for fast/slow queries?

Comment: Good call @Abe Miessler - @Bryce Wagner may be seeing improvement after updating statistics because the UDPATE uses a new execution plan.

Comment: In this case, yeah, I'm sure I know better than the optimizer, in certain situations it was doing an index scan on a completely irrelevant index.  Including the WITH INDEX fixed most of the optimizer issues, I'm just confused why it didn't fix all of them.

Comment: I did look at the estimated execution plan when it was running slow, it said it expected 92% of the time doing index seeks on my forced index.

Comment: That would make sense. Doesn't mean it wouldn't run faster with a different index...

Answer (score 1):

When the auto stats are on, the engine would like to update the stats [quite often](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195565), usually way more often than nightly:

```
 Table Type | Empty Condition | Threshold When Empty |Threshold When Not Empty 
_________________________________________________________________________________
 Permanent  | < 500 rows      | # of Changes >= 500  | # of Changes >= 500 + (20% of Cardinality)
___________________________________________________________________________
 Temporary  | < 6 rows        | # of Changes >= 6    | # of Changes >= 500 + (20% of Cardinality)
```

But why not take out the guess and simply deploy a plan guide? See [Understanding Plan Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx).

Comment: I used "sp_autostats <table_name>, <stats_flag>, <index_name>" from that first link, to make sure statistics were turned on on the index.  I also ran "sp_dboption <dbname>,'auto create statistics', 'on'" just to be sure they were actually on (even though the boxes were checked).  If it's not better behaved next week, I'll look into creating a plan guide.

Comment: Messing around with the auto statistics flags didn't have any effect, so I started investigating plan guides.  Turns out they only apply to SQL 2005 and later, not 2000.  So no go on that.